# Postgresql SQL SELECT oldest item but debounced

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that look like:

| id | Value | Created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Apple' | 2021-12-25T20:15:00 |
| 2 | 'Blueberry' | 2021-12-25T20:45:00 |
| 3 | 'Cranberry' | 2021-12-25T21:30:00 |
| 4 | 'Durian' | 2022-01-01T20:15:00 |
| 5 | 'Elderbery' | 2022-01-01T20:30:00 |

I'm looking to write a query where I get the oldest document, with the caveat that if another row was created within an hour, it will return that row instead. For example, in the above I would like to return `Cranberry`. Initially pick `Apple`, but since `Blueberry` comes within an hour, move to that one, and since `Cranberry` comes within an hour of `Blueberry`, select `Cranberry`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the difference with the next row (ordered by `Created`) using `lead`, then check for the first row for which the following row comes after a full hour:

```
select id, Value, Created from
(select id, Value, Created,
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM lead(Created) over(order by Created) - Created)/3600 as diff
from table_name) t
where diff > 1 or diff is null
order by Created
limit 1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=395c0dda53213372db6454b674f49d8d)